# Target CSS class using nested declaration but only using a partial matcher for the Classes on the elements

Tags: css

Trying to style a JS chart.  The Chart generates an ID value every time it loads so I have to target it using a partial match like this:

```
path[class^='fillSelection-upset-'] {...}
```

which works great.  However I need to target the `text` element that comes right after that `path` element (siblings) and change the text to white when it is hovered over

What I have tried is

```
path[class^='fillSelection-upset-'] ~ text[class^='valueTextStyle-upset-']
```

and

```
path[class^='fillSelection-upset-'] + text[class^='valueTextStyle-upset-']
```

But neither of those target the element.

Comment: Strange, as it works with ordinary html elements: https://codepen.io/angelhearted/pen/VwBbMjM

Comment: @NikitaSkrebets Ya that is strange thanks for putting that together.  Must have to do with the class changing via JS, but that always applies the class under normal circumstances.  Maybe this just won't work.  Thanks again!